# Vagrant / VirtualBox DNS 10.0.2.3 not working

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualbox, vagrant

I am running a fresh install of Linux Mint Nadia (14). I am following the instructions on Vagrant [Getting Started](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/) but have gotten stuck on the [Provisioning](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/). It seems the Vagrant box cannot connect outside and so I can't install anything using either Chef or Puppet.

In the basic Vagrant `resolve.conf` contains `nameserver 10.0.2.3`. But with that set I can't ping `us.archive.ubuntu.com`.

If I change it to `8.8.8.8` then I can ping `us.archive.ubuntu.com` but it does not stay set, and after a reboot it changes back to `10.0.2.3` - so provisioning fails again.

Ideally I would like for `10.0.2.3` to work on my setup. Failing that I would like a way to permanently change `resolv.conf` so that I can do provisioning.

Comment: FYI that I just hit this same problem with the `ubuntu/xenial64` box, and it turned out to be [a bug with the box itself](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1621393).

Comment: @AidanFeldman same for me. Just switched to `bento/ubuntu-16.04` and DNS works fine without any further fixes.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can work around this issue in one of two ways, both of which are [in the VirtualBox manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#nat-adv-dns):

> #### Enabling DNS proxy in NAT mode
>
> The NAT engine by default offers the same DNS servers to the guest
>   that are configured on the host. In some scenarios, it can be
>   desirable to hide the DNS server IPs from the guest, for example when
>   this information can change on the host due to expiring DHCP leases.
>   In this case, you can tell the NAT engine to act as DNS proxy using
>   the following command:
>
> ```
> VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnsproxy1 on
> ```
>
> #### Using the host's resolver as a DNS proxy in NAT mode
>
> For resolving network names, the DHCP server of the NAT engine offers
>   a list of registered DNS servers of the host. If for some reason you
>   need to hide this DNS server list and use the host's resolver
>   settings, thereby forcing the VirtualBox NAT engine to intercept DNS
>   requests and forward them to host's resolver, use the following
>   command:
>
> ```
> VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnshostresolver1 on
> ```
>
> Note that this setting is similar to the DNS proxy mode, however
>   whereas the proxy mode just forwards DNS requests to the appropriate
>   servers, the resolver mode will interpret the DNS requests and use the
>   host's DNS API to query the information and return it to the guest.

Comment: Thank you. "Using the host's resolver as a DNS proxy in NAT mode" did the trick. It is just a pity I have to do this for every Vagrant install.

Comment: I almost always use bridged mode for VMs, which eliminates the problem (and a whole host of other problems).

Comment: Just had the issue with an upgrade to the 4.2.20,  "Using the host's resolver as a DNS proxy in NAT mode" did the trick for me too. Thx !

Comment: Neither of these work for me with hashicorp/bionic64 FML

Answer (score 78):

Following up on https://serverfault.com/a/453260/14832, if you're using a version 2 Vagrantfile config format, the one which starts:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
```

Then you might want to add this to that config file:

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
end
```

If you're using the old config format, but are using Vagrant 1.1+, you can append this at the end of the file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
  end
end
```

Comment: Adding this to my `Vagrantfile` fixed the problem where I could not run `gem install...` without getting silly DNS errors :) Thanks!

Comment: did not work for me... not sure what I'm missing

Comment: @NickHall Check the VM inside if it has static IP assigned; if so -- check the reachablitiy of the nameserver from `/etc/resolv.conf`; if it's `10.0.2.3`, check my answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

Necromancing this one as in my opinion none of the answers shed any light on the *root cause* of this problem, which seems quite interesting. For modern context -- the issue also happens with Debian 10, and VirtualBox 6.0.14; after default install of Deb 10 (GUI-less), with one "NAT" adapter (not "NAT Network", but the default "NAT") all seems OK with DNS. Then upon changing `/etc/network/interfaces` (which seems still relevant in this distro) to static IP:

```
#iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
iface enp0s3 inet static
address 10.0.2.15
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.2.2
```

(note -- the VM would have got `10.0.2.15` from dhcp anyway), and powering off/on the VM,

- DNS does not work (`host google.com` etc, timeout)
- can't `telnet 10.0.2.3 53` (`resolv.conf` has `nameserver 10.0.2.3`, per default after installation).

If I revert to `iface enp0s3 inet dhcp` and *reboot* the VM, DNS and `telnet 10.0.2.3 53` work.

Now it gets really exciting/bizzare: if you again go for `inet static`, and *just reboot* the VM, the DNS & telnet *still work OK*; only if you do power off/on the VM (via virtualbox), the `10.0.2.3` disappears.

So my guess at the moment is, that VirtualBox *automagically* turns on the DNS server/proxy at `10.0.2.3` once it gets a `dhcp` request; and this `10.0.2.3` lives for as long as the VM is not power-off-ed (but can be rebooted).

(I would check this if I knew how to fake a `dhcp` request on the `10.0.2.0/24`; does anyone know how?)

__

Bottom line for those who do want to change IP to static (in the "NAT" adapter): just find a way to paste proper `nameserver` into `/etc/resolv.conf` (can be after startup in some init scripts).

Answer (score 0):

On the VagrantVM, try:

```
resolvectl dns eth0 your_server_dns_ip_address
```

for example

```
resolvectl dns eth0 8.8.8.8
```