# Vagrant: Slow internet connection in guest

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I'm trying to set up a vagrant. Host is Ubuntu 12.10. Here's my vagrant file:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|

    config.vm.share_folder("v-root", "/vagrant", ".", :nfs => true)
    config.vm.network :bridged, :bridge => "eth0"

    config.vm.define "restserver" do |chefs_config|

        chefs_config.vm.box = "precise64"
        chefs_config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"
        chefs_config.vm.host_name = "restserver"
        chefs_config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.20.50"
        chefs_config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080

        config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|

            chef.log_level = :debug

            chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
            chef.run_list.clear

            chef.add_recipe "apt"
            chef.add_recipe "base"
            chef.add_recipe "mongodb::default"
            chef.add_recipe "nginx"
        end
    end
end
```

The problem is that my internet access from within the vagrant is terrible. It's very slow. I think the routing tables might be messed up. Here's the output from `route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.20.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
```

There are 2 routes to the default destination, although on the same NIC and to the same gateway. But perhaps this is causing an issue. At least that's what I thought but deleting the first default route doesn't help.

I need host-only networking so the nfs share will work. NAT is used for the port forwarding, and I've added the bridged network to try to give this guest access to the internet.

Has anyone any idea what's wrong? DNS is very slow to resolve, and it's slow to download anything from the internet.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Answer:

Add the following to the vagrant config:

```
config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
```

See here for more: [Vagrant / VirtualBox DNS 10.0.2.3 not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/453185/vagrant-virtualbox-dns-10-0-2-3-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: This almost fixed it for me, except that there wasn't a `customize` method on `config.vm`. Instead, on my `    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|` section, I added this:

      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]

Comment: The answer provided by 'sarah' is for the old VagrantFile configuration syntax, and the one provided by 'Ovid' is for the newer configuration syntax.

You can tell if you're using the newer syntax by seeing if your configuration file includes `Vagrant.configure(2)` at the top (note the `2`)

Comment: almost. this works for me https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1807#issuecomment-19132198 vagrant 1.4.3

Comment: I'm on Fedora 22 and setting this to `"off"` was my solution.

Answer (score 31):

### Running Version 2 of the Vagrant config?

[Sarah's](https://serverfault.com/users/167715/sarah) provided the answer which is to use the NAT hosts DNS resolver as it's faster and will help speed things up.

However, in Version 2 of the vagrant config which is what most people are using now you'll have to do add following within your 'Vagrantfile' which will force the VM to uses NAT'd DNS:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
   v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
   v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
end
```

You can tell if you're using v2 config if you have the following lines or something in the top of your `Vagrantfile`

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
```

Comment: This should be the right answer

Comment: I tried to boost my vagrant network and it worked, but I had issues with e.g. pulling docker images because of too much DNS lookups. Thus I had to remove this line 

`v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]`

means I just have this added to my `Vagrantfile`

`v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]`

Looks like the host resolver is boosting the network performance for some reason and the DNS proxy frags some tools.

Comment: THANK YOU! My vm was taking FOREVER to up and ssh into--it would usually just timeout--when connected to the internet/the network. This fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The NAT settings didn't improve my download speed.

I had to use the following setting to get proper download rates.

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"]
end
```